# How to use SVN post-commit hook trigger jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins, svn, post-commit-hook

The main purpose is that I want to commit some files to SVN repository and trigger the jenkins to build some test automatically.The method I want to use is post-commit hook.

I use TortoiseSVN , and I create a repository to test.
I change the post-commit.tmpl to post-commit.bat which is in D:\Repository\hooks folder.

below is what in the post-commit.bat : (Windows 10)

```
SET REPOS=%1
SET REV=%2

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (
'svnlook uuid %REPOS%'
) DO (
SET UUID=%%a
)

FOR /f "tokens=*" %%b IN (
'svnlook changed --revision %REV% %REPOS%'
) DO (
SET POST=%%b
)

D:/Wget/wget ^
    --header="Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" ^
    --post-data="%POST%" ^
    --output-document="-" ^
    --timeout=2 ^
    http://localhost:8080/jenkins/subversion/%UUID%/notifyCommit?rev=%REV%
```

the error messages is:

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code 8)with output:
--2019-09-23 13:50:53-- 
http://localhost:8080/"realUUID"/notifyCommit?rev=7
Resolving localhost(localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost(localhost)|::1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-09-23 13:50:53 ERROR 404: Not Found
```

what I have done is:
1.change jenkins settings to "Allow anonymous read access"
2.cancel CSRF protection

I have no idea what is the main step that SVN communicate with Jenkins.

Please help , and thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you receive is `HTTP 404 NOT FOUND` and you need to examine your hook script for errors:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-09-23 13:50:53 ERROR 404: Not Found
```

Therefore, the URL that `wget` contacts is *invalid*: `http://localhost:8080/jenkins/subversion/%UUID%/notifyCommit?rev=%REV%`. You need to double-check the URL for typos and that the %UUID% is correct. Note that I do not see any SET for %UUID% in your hook - maybe it is the problem?